# Hybrid Authentication - What to do on session expiration?

Tags: php, session, authentication, hybridauth

I've written a system based on the HybridAuth library available here: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

The user can login using Facebook, Twitter, and the sites local login system.

However I'm wondering what should happen when the PHP session expires (24 minutes currently - default setting). Previously with single sign on systems I've just redirected the user there and should they have checked remember me it automatically re-establishes there connection.

Now though I have three methods in which a user can login.

These are the options I've come up with so far:

- Try connecting with each of the available authentication methods until a connection is found
- Store a cookie client side with information of which authentication provider the user last used and only try that one
- Force the user to choose how to login again (not ideal)

If anyone has any suggestions please share.

Answer (score 1):

I would save a cookie with login information containing the login method and use that everytime the session expires.

If the user login using another method I would replace the old cookie (or the old login method) with the new one.

So Your second option.

The third is confusing for the user and the first one is unnecessarily resources consumpting...

Comment: Cool option two was the one I was leaning towards but wanted to see what others thought. Will leave the question open for a few days in case anyone else has better solutions/options. Cheers.